# Send SMS via Bit Web Server calling android intent

Tags: android, web-services, android-intent, sms

I'd like to create a php script that runs under a web server on Android (in my case bit web server) that sends sms using the sim of my phone.
Is it possible to do this or I have to create a dedicated app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use php to send messages from your phone's sim, just any page out there on the internet would have been able to do that. You need to create a dedicated application for that and get the permission from the user before being able to do it.

Comment: You're right, so if I use this open source web server do you think I can call the sms intent to send a message? https://github.com/DroidPHP/DroidPHP

Comment: Technically you can, but you'll have to modify the Java code of the web server application to call the intent when it receives some signal from the web page.